# SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS not working on VS Code MSSQL extension

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, visual-studio-code, transactions

To disable autocommit in MS SQL Server, I use the command in dbeaver

```
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON
```

And all the subsequent DMLs executed on the same connection within dbeaver does NOT commit automatically which works as expected

However, this doesn't seem to be working in VS Code extension from Microsoft "mssql" (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-mssql.mssql). The session mode automatically switches back to enabling autocommit. Why does this occur? Is there a way to workaround this?

Comment: [I can't replicate your issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqdk0.png).

Comment: Why would you *want* `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS` very few people actually want it on?

Comment: @Larnu Thanks. Are you executing the entire script in one go? It works in that way, but if it is executed one by one by selecting and executing (Ctrl-Shift-E), it always goes back to default of OFF.

Comment: @Charlieface I want to play with some DML stuff and then rollback or commit as and when required. Plus I come from an Oracle background where this autocommit is not ON by default.

Comment: At best this sounds like a bug with the extension, and should be reported on their Github (I can replicate the same behaviour in ADS). Though you could solve the issue by using explicit transactions if you want to mess around with stuff.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu , It works correctly in dbeaver. So odd that MS products like ADS have this bug.

Comment: It works only for one session, if you create new connection you have to add it again into your query. You can set your environment in https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Connection-Types/ in connection type by "Auto-commit by default" functionality.

Comment: @Deadsheep39 Thanks for your comment, but I want the opposite of what you seem to suggest. Auto-commit to be disabled and on VS Code extension. Dbeaver works just fine in this regard.